# How do I swap two lines in vim?

Tags: vim

I have this:

```
pick 887b66f add 222 Dziewiecsil to flowers new title
pick dc331cb new name of beginning commit
```

And I want to get this:

```
pick dc331cb new name of beginning commit
pick 887b66f add 222 Dziewiecsil to flowers new title
```

Is there a way to do this in a quick way using keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: You might consider using a different editor if you are not familiar with vim.  You can configure the editor for git only using either `git config --global core.editor <whatever>`, or for many things at once (including git) by including `export EDITOR=<whatever>` in your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

To swap the current line with the next one, type `ddp` while in command mode.

- dd - delete line (actually called cut in other editors) and save it in register
- p - paste line from register

Comment: Move the cursor on the first line, then type `ddp`.  If you are not in command mode yet, hit `Esc` to get into command mode.

Comment: `dd` deletes the current line after copying it into a "register". `p` copies ("puts") the contents of the register into your buffer *after* the current line. Similarly, you can swap two characters with `xp`, or two words with `dwwP`.

Comment: @KeithThompson unfortunately, not as easy as that to swap two words.

Comment: @CS Are you referring to the fact that `dwwP` doesn't work the same way if the two words are at the end of a line? (And swapping the last word on one line with the first word on the following line is even trickier.)

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah, although I felt kinda bad after making my comment because that's a literal edge case ;)

Comment: Very useful to use with macro, using `q`.

Comment: I know both `dd` and `p`, but just never occurred to me i can do in a combo. Amazing!

Answer (score 73):

`dd` deletes the current line, then you can paste the removed line using `p`. There's another way though using `m`. With `m` you can move lines around i.e.

`:m 1` will move the current line after line 1

`:m 0` will move the current line to top

`:m $` will move the current line to bottom

In your example, place the cursor in the first line and type `:m $`

More info: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down

Comment: Thanks for the explanation for non vim "natives" :-)

Comment: This is the answer that I was also looking for to expand my knowledge of vim.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I've been looking for. This can become even handier when swiping multiple lines at the same time using the visual mode.

Comment: This is great! much more versatile than the chosen answer! :)

Answer (score 26):

Example:

```
  1. one
> 2. two
```

with `:m-2`, switch (current line - 2)

```
> 2. two
  1. one
```

with `:m+1` switch (current line + 1)

```
  1. one
> 2. two
```

You could map this if you want.

Comment: Eg https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/bubble.vim

Comment: This is the better answer than the default answer

Answer (score 14):

Despite the fact that question is quite old and marked as answered, I'd like to extend the answer by saying that you can use normal mode commands, which were provided by [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178239/how-do-i-swap-two-lines-in-vim/28178353#28178353) with `nnoremap` like so:

```
:nnoremap <C-Up> <Up>ddp<Up>
:nnoremap <C-Down> ddp
```

This will allow you to move lines with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> within your file. However this will overwrite `@"` register, which stores your last copied string/word/letter/etc. So by adding "(reg) before `dd` and `p` commands we can fix this:

```
:nnoremap <C-Up> <Up>"add"ap<Up>
:nnoremap <C-Down> "add"ap
```

Here we add `"a` before delete and paste commands to store our line in `@a` register, so your default copy register will not be overwritten. However it may overwrite contents of `@a` register (who knows, but you may use it for something important in your use-case, but this step bit paranoid, you can skip it if you want to), let's fix that too:

```
:nnoremap <silent><C-Up> :let save_a=@a<Cr><Up>"add"ap<Up>:let @a=save_a<Cr>
:nnoremap <silent><C-Down> :let save_a=@a<Cr>"add"ap:let @a=save_a<Cr>
```

(`<silent>` needed to prevent echoing our commands to message-line at the bottom.)

Now we have two mappings which allow us to move lines within the file with keyboard shortcuts. You can redefine buttons, I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>, which would be `<A-j>` and `<A-k>` for those commands. However not all terminal emulators support Alt key mappings AFAIK.

Answer (score 7):

The mappings proposed in the Vim [wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down) page are actually the best way to map key combinations that emulate the way Sublime and other editors implement this feature.

This includes an indentation action after the move, which is also great (that's the double equal `==` signs, in case you don't want that).

It also supports **visual** and **insert** modes, so that you can move lines while editing or with fulblocks.

```
nnoremap <A-j> :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap <A-k> :m .-2<CR>==
inoremap <A-j> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
inoremap <A-k> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi
vnoremap <A-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <A-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

I personally mapped them to `<D-J>` and `<D-K>` on my Mac, instead of `<A-` which maps to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. That way I use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>, which feels more natural to my fingertips.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Using the Alt modifier suits the task well. Thank you!