# How to reorder last two commits in git?

Tags: git

I want to reorder last two commits in git:

right now I have:

```
$ git log --oneline -4
1e0ecba (HEAD, my-branch) Fix for T255
82d45dc django_extensions
af3953b improvements according to CR
dae63ff Fullscreen support
```

I want to have:

```
$ git log --oneline -4
82d45dc (HEAD, my-branch) django_extensions
1e0ecba Fix for T255
af3953b improvements according to CR
dae63ff Fullscreen support
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In general you have to use `git rebase --interactive` - here is detail answer [how to reorder any number of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740537/reordering-of-commits):

But if you want to reorder **last two commits** you can use this git alias:

Add to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    reorder = "!GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=\"sed -i -n 'h;1n;2p;g;p'\" git rebase -i HEAD~2"
```

and then:

```
$ git reorder
Rebasing(2/2)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/my-branch.
```

Comment: I'd personally stick with just a plain vanilla interactive rebase.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I needed this alias because I like to keep some personal adjustments to code in my last commit. During development, when I create new commits I need to reorder my-special-commit to keep it as last... and If I want to push this, I do: git push origin HEAD~1:my-branch

Comment: To make it work on macos systems, go with "sed -i '' -n" instead of "sed -i -n".

Comment: @noisy In that case, I would prefer to commit your local changes to a local branch, and then just merge the public development into your adjusted branch. Make changes while you are on your branch, then, when you are ready to commit, checkout the last public commit, commit your changes, get back to your local branch, and merge your new commit. That way you get a full locally working history, never have to rebase, and public history stays clean of your local changes.

Comment: This was very handy to programatically amend the commit message of the second last commit in many git repos (quite the esoteric use case I admit)

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I was looking for, thank you.
If anyone is wondering, in case of conflicts between the two commits, rebase will apply the first commit (originally HEAD), and then stay in conflict state waiting for you to: skip commit, fix conflicts or abort rebase.

Answer (score 147):

I truly recommend to read [this answer about how to reorder commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2740812/2874896), you'll feel like a git rockstar afterwards, I promise.

---

Apart from that, here's how you do it with a simple rebase (assuming you're standing on the branch you want to rebase):

`git rebase -i HEAD~2`

Next, **change** the order of the commits in the prompt.

```
pick f4648aee My first commit
pick 00adf09a My second commit
```

to

```
pick 00adf09a My second commit
pick f4648aee My first commit
```

Unbelievable that it can be that simple, if you ask me.

Comment: It's not that simple in case there were changes in each commit. You need to  manually edit the merge if it can't automatically merge the changes, then add the files back.

Comment: vim command for quickly swapping two lines:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178239/how-do-i-swap-two-lines-in-vim

Comment: This is helpful, meanwhile I just want to add a link about how to easily move a line in vi: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2674/how-can-i-easily-move-a-line

Comment: Come across a powerful tool to move one line or a range of lines, refer to this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50151997/9330812

Answer (score 10):

Assuming no conflicts:

- `git rebase -i HEAD~4`
- Re-order commits + save

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I have written the following answer from the standpoint of understanding how few git commands work. The other answers will get your work done in a shorter way with the help of interactive rebase commands. I had encountered this similar situation and this is how I solved my problem -

Suppose this is how your last 4 commits look like.

```
* ca6807e - (HEAD -> lolo) third (4 seconds ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
| 
* 61a069c - (master) fourth (18 hours ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
| 
* f3b0255 - (lol) second (2 days ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
| 
* c2f5e4f - first (2 days ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
```

Now according to your question you want to make the commit history as follows (Ignore the rest of the commit ids)-

```
* 0fe6482 - (HEAD -> master) fourth (5 seconds ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
| 
* 2c3ba40 - (lol) third (4 minutes ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
| 
* f3b0255 - (lolo) second (2 days ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
| 
* c2f5e4f - first (2 days ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
```

To do that follow these steps -

1. Go to the 3rd last commit

   `git reset HEAD~2`

   Now your HEAD will point at the 'second' commit
2. At this point, we will switch our branch from master to lol (look at the first tree diagram)-

   `git checkout lol`

   Now if you do `git status` you may find some files are in the untracked 
   section that is because you checked back to a previous commit in the 
   history which which did not have those files in tracking mode but your remote 
   repository has them. So you have to just ignore those files for now. But git 
   will not let you move forward with our approach if we keep those files 
   untracked. So we add all of them by doing `git add *` followed by `git 
   stash` which will save those files in a temporary stack (ignoring them 
   temporarily and then allowing us to pop those files from this stack later when 
   we need).
3. Now we need to move our 'fourth' commit on the current branch 'lol'. To do 
   that we need to use `git cherry-pick` command. Copy the commit id of the 
   'fourth' commit which is `ca6807e` in my case. Now type `git cherry-pick ca6807e`. Now the tree structure will look something like this -

   ```
   * 2c3ba40 - (HEAD -> lol) third (3 seconds ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
   |   
   | * 61a069c - (master) fourth (18 hours ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
   |/  
   | 
   * f3b0255 - (lolo) second (2 days ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
   | 
   * c2f5e4f - first (2 days ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
   ```

Now you just need to do switch back to master branch and rebase lol branch on it.

```
git checkout master
git rebase lol
```

And now you have successfully interchanged the last two commits. Here is how the tree structure looks like now -

```
* 0fe6482 - (HEAD -> master) fourth (5 seconds ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
| 
* 2c3ba40 - (lol) third (4 minutes ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
| 
* f3b0255 - (lolo) second (2 days ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
| 
* c2f5e4f - first (2 days ago) <Kaustubh Butte>
```